# Can't generate word cloud by cluster number using R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to generate a word cloud by cluster but it gives error x must be an array of atleast two dimensions, I am using twitter data -> corpus -> textminig -> document term matrix -> kmeans clustering -> word cloud by each cluster.

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(XML)
library(streamR)
library(wordcloud)
library(NLP) 
library(fpc)
library(cluster)

tweetsDF <- parseTweets('tweetsStream.txt', simplify = FALSE)
names(tweetsDF)

corp = Corpus(VectorSource(tweetsDF$text))
inspect(corp[1:1])

corp = Corpus(VectorSource(corp))
dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
inspect(dtm)

tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(corp)

freq = colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
length(freq)

freq= sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm)), decreasing = TRUE)
head(freq, 14)

d= dist(t(dtm), method="euclidian")
kfit <- kmeans(d, 2)
clusplot(as.matrix(d), kfit$cluster, color=T, shade=T, labels=2, lines=0)

docs1 = names(which(kfit$cluster ==2))
docs1 = as.matrix(docs1)
v1= sort(colSums((docs1)), decreasing= TRUE)
```

[error x must be an array of at least two dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B6fZ.png)

```
myNames1 = names(v1)
d1 = data.frame(word=myNames1, freq=v1)
wordcloud(d1$word, d1$freq, min.freq=2)
```

[output of dput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klaU8.png)

Comment: Please `dput()` some sample data. Also please include your library statements.

Comment: @Hack-R - sorry where i can use dput()?

Comment: In R you just use it like this `dput(my_data)` then copy and paste the output to Stack Overflow

Comment: Or `dput(head(tweetsDF))`

Comment: @Hack-R, did u find any solution?

Comment: @boshek ,dput contains link and this doesn't allow me to copy paste i have added image of that

Comment: Create a minimal example. You don't need all those columns to get `wordcloud()` working. Folks will help you but it is inefficient if you don't provide something to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not collecting the term data after clustering to determine the word clouds....

What you what should be something like this:

```
library(slam)

docs1 <- which(kfit$cluster ==2)
head(docs1); length(docs1)
docs1 <- tdm[docs1, ]
head(docs1)
d1 <- data.frame(word=rownames(docs1), freq=row_sums(docs1))
head(d1)
d1 <- d1[order(d1$freq), ]
wordcloud(d1$word, d1$freq, min.freq=2)
```

### Minimal example:

Using some built in data I have done kmeans clustering and generated a wordcloud based on one of the clusters

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(slam)

data("acq")

dtm = DocumentTermMatrix(acq)
inspect(dtm)

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(acq)

freq = colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
length(freq)

freq= sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm)), decreasing = TRUE)
head(freq, 14)

d= dist(t(dtm), method="euclidian")
kfit <- kmeans(d, 2)
clusplot(as.matrix(d), kfit$cluster, color=T, shade=T, labels=2, lines=0)

docs1 <- which(kfit$cluster ==2)
head(docs1); length(docs1)
docs1 <- tdm[docs1, ]
inspect(docs1)
d1 <- data.frame(word=rownames(docs1), freq=row_sums(docs1))
head(d1)
d1 <- d1[order(d1$freq), ]
wordcloud(d1$word, d1$freq, min.freq=2)
```

As a side note: posting an image of your `dput` statement doesn;t help as we cannot use this to generate your data on our machines.

Comment: it gives an error "x must be an array of at least two dimension".

Comment: >docs1 = names(which(kfit$cluster ==2))
    > docs1 = tdm[docs1, ]
   Error: object 'tdm' not found
  > docs1 = tdm[docs1, ]
  Error: object 'tdm' not found

Comment: docs1 = names(which(kfit$cluster ==2))                                                     docs1 = tdm[docs1, ]                                                                                    d1 <- data.frame(word=names(docs1), freq=rowSums(docs1))
    Error in rowSums(docs1) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: I made an edit above do the first docs1 assignment, as well as added some checks

Comment: Sorry emilliman5 It gives the same error: x must be an array of atleast two dimensions

Comment: Create an example. The folks here are being very patient.

Comment: length(docs1)
[1] 148
> docs1 <- tdm[docs1, ]
> head(docs1)
Error in x$nrow : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: length(docs1)
    [1] 148
    > docs1 <- tdm[docs1, ]
    > head(docs1)
    Error in x$nrow : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
    > docs1
    A term-document matrix (148 terms, 993 documents)

    Non-/sparse entries: 4369/142595
    Sparsity           : 97%
    Maximal term length: 192  
    Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
    > d1 <- data.frame(word=names(docs1), freq=rowSums(docs1))
    Error in rowSums(docs1) : 'x' must be an array of at least two       dimensions

Comment: `rowSums` does not work on `tdm` because it is a sparse matrix, either load the `slam` package or `rowSums(as.matrix(docs1)` Depending on the size of your data `row_sums` is the better option because it does not coerce the sparse matrix to a dense one which can quickly generate an overflow situation, especially with text data.

Comment: boss,you are debugging the code, great.                                                    > d1 = data.frame(word=names(docs1),                                                  > freq=rowSums(as.matrix((docs1))))                                                               
Error in data.frame(word = names(docs1),                                                   freq = rowSums(as.matrix((docs1)))) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 148

Comment: length(rowSums(as.matrix(docs1)))
[1] 148       and       
> length(names(docs1))
[1] 6

Comment: I have posted a minimal example that works... please get your data into it and try it.  `names` does not work on a matrix you need to use either `rownames` or `colnames` (again this was in the new example code)

Comment: Thank you so much @emilliman5.  Finally it works. Thank you so again for  keeping patience and answered my question and error without data, sorry for that as well :) Great Scientist!

Comment: Sorry, @emilliman, i accepted the answer, actually i am new to this thats why, thanks again.